# Issue with Collation in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as

```
mysql> show create table tbl_name\G
```

********************* 1. row ***************************

```
   Table: tbl_name

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tbl_name` (
  `name` char(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin7 COLLATE=latin7_estonian_cs
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

The DATA In Table is as

```
mysql> select * from tbl_name;

 name       id 
 manaf      1 
 manaf      2 
 MANAF      3 
 MAnaf      4
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Now i want the Case Sensitivity in all the records

```
mysql> select distinct(name) from tbl_name;
```

It should return the 3 rows in result but it is returing just 1.why..??
As I have set the table collation as latin7_estonian_cs

Comment: Isn't it `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM .....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY value FROM tableName
```

[Reference](http://venutip.com/content/case-sensitivity-mysql-do-you-really-need-it)